# How Do You find The Cutoff Frequency of a Low Pass Filter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, thevenin, low-pass

[image: Circuit]

A lowpass filter exists around R1,R2,R3 and C2 but how would you find the cutoff frequency?

I think that you have to first find the Thevenin equivalent circuit and this is what i got:

RTH = (R1//R3)//R2 = 960.6 Ohms.

Then cutoff frequency is
Wc = 1/(2*pi*RC) = 1.66 Hz
I think this is wrong because it is extremely small, can anyone help me understand.

Comment: Wouldn't Rth = R3 s (R1 || R2)

Comment: R3 is 100k, so charges C2 very slowly... try with R3 = 1k.

Comment: The values aren't necessarily important, its just how to get the Thevenin equivalent

Comment: @John It's pretty much what it looks like. \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ form a voltage divider. This makes an equivalent \$V_\text{TH}\$ and series \$R_\text{TH}\$. The series \$R_\text{TH}\$ can then be combined with \$R_3\$ by just adding them. This now forms up a simple RC low-pass filter with \$C_2\$. \$R_4\$ doesn't really matter so long as you don't have more information about the circuit and its usage, so ignore it for these considerations. The cutoff is even smaller in frequency than you calculated.

Comment: Build the circuit and measure :) Always works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R1 || R2 = 969.89 ohms. It is less than 1% of 100K but just to be accurate; 100K - 969.89 = 99,030.11 ohms = 62.22 seconds or 0.01607 HZ as a full cycle. Basically a half minute to charge or discharge the capacitor to pi.

Note that R3 dominates the time-constant for both charge and discharge, so while R1 and R2 are important in terms of current source and sink (and the maximum charge voltage for C2), they have little effect on timing.